# 18.04 Right Clicks misfiring

Tags: gnome, 18.04, mouse

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME, though I believe the problem existed before I installed GNOME, but I did so very soon after upgrading due to touchscreen issues with the default UI. Right clicking works, but very often right clicking once will end up firing the event twice. I'm using a usb mouse which works perfectly fine on Windows on the same machine and so I have no idea what the issue is. I've tried finding a similar question but could only find issues where the key didn't work at all. It's beginning to become very annoying as I may have to right click 4 or 5 times in a row to get the desired result without it doubling.